# ng reflect model not updating select value - while updating the field page

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<select (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)" [ngModel] = "post?.requirement" name="requirement" #requirement="ngModel" class="form-control">
<option value="default">Select category</option>
<option value="add">Add new category</option>
</select>
selectChangeHandler(event: any)
```

{this.selectedOption = event.target.value;}

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: ng reflect model not updating select value in angular 2 and above version.

Comment: You have not included it in the select tag. Then how will it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select placeholder="Please select" id="myselect" class="form-control" 
              (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)" [ngModel] = "post?.requirement" name="requirement" 
              #requirement="ngModel">
                  <option value="FIT (Customised) Tour Package">FIT (Customised) Tour Package</option></select>

 selectChangeHandler(event: any): void {
    this.selectedOption = event.target.value;
  }
```

Comment: Can u please help me on above scenario??
ng reflect model not updating select value